# ¿Dibujar una linea en una imagen PhotoImage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, imagen

Hay alguna manera de dibujar una linea en una imagen usando PhotoImage en tkinter.Estoy haciendo una app de dibujo y me gustaria poder guardar la imagen usando el método `.write()`.Por eso necesito saber si hay alguna manera de dibujar una linea sobre una imagen.

**Algo asi**

```
imagen.line(from_=(0,0),to=(450,345))
```

Si hay alguna alternativa o otra manera de hacerlo hagan saber en las respuestas.

**Atencion:Usando solo tkinter,no PIL ni otra libreria,solo TKINTER**.

Muchas gracias a los que respondan esta pregunta :).

Comment: Por que no querés usar pillow? PhotoImage casi no tiene caracteristicas de dibujo. Eso te obligará a crear tu propia librería de dibujo usando matematica y programación. La misma duda te va a surgir cuando quieras hacer circulos, cuadrados, triangulos, etc. Pillow ya viene con todo eso resuelto. Aun así querés una respuesta sin usar ninguna librería?

Comment: ya gracias,he usado los cosenos y senos para hacer círculos,con esta formula x=Xcentro+cos (angulo)*radio.   y=Ycentro+sen (angulo)*radio.   por favor abstente de hacer ese tipo de comentarios que no aportan solucion. ;) @DanteS.

Comment: Disculpa? Mi comentario aporta. Solo te aconseje que recurras a Pillow por que te podría hacer mucho mas facil el trabajo. Que me haya tomado el tiempo de comentar para ayudarte para que me digas "tu comentario no sirve, no digas mas" no me cae bien. Que esperas? Que te de un código hecho a tu medida sin ayudarte a aprender? Olvidalo. Si no hubieras dicho lo ultimo, te estaría escribiendo una respuesta. Es probable que hayas perdido la respuesta del que más sabe Tkinter aquí...

Comment: Perdon no queria que te enojaras,enserio perdon si dije algo ofensivo la verdad no volvera a pasar.Enserio no queria hacer algun comentario malo o ofensivo.Tambien es obvio que desearia una respuesta que podria ser mas efectiva que mi solución. @DanteS.

Comment: Te perdono, gracias por las disculpas c:

Answer (score 2):

Photoimage apenas tiene los métodos de dibujo necesarios para interactuar con la imagen. Así que no hay una forma built-in de hacer una linea, pero podemos recrearla nosotros mismos usando matematica.

#### Fundamentos matematicos

Si conocemos los puntos que unen la linea, obtenemos esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y sabemos que solo existe una linea que une los dos puntos.

Si revisas detenidamente, se forma un triangulo rectangulo. Donde las formulas para obtener cada cateto son `p2x - p1x` y `p2y - p1y`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, queremos conocer el punto donde pasa la linea en cierta coordenada x:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como el triangulo empieza en p1, la formula para obtener ax relativo al triangulo es `ax - p1x`.

Como podremos ver, formamos otro triangulo rectangulo, y lo más curioso, es que el angulo formado desde p1 es el mismo para ambos triangulos. Eso significa que si calculamos el angulo de uno de los triangulos, tendremos el angulo de otro.

Vamos a usar la ecuación de la tangente (`tan(alpha) = co / ca`) para obtener el angulo usando de referencia el triangulo rectangulo que incluye a la linea completa:

```
tan(alpha) = (p2y - p1y) / (p2x - p1x)
```

Oh, que pasó? No, no está incompleto, resulta que no necesitamos saber el angulo. Nos alcanza con conocer la tangente, ya que esto nos dará la tangente del OTRO triangulo rectangulo. En este caso, incluiremos las variables y (es la posición y del )

```
tan(alpha) = (ay - p1y) / (ax - p1x)
```

ax lo conocemos, ya que es el x visitado actualmente a la hora de dibujar la linea. la tangente de alpha también la conocemos, la calculamos antes usando p1 y p2 y va a ser exactamente la misma sin importar que valor tenga ax.

Despejando ay

```
tan(alpha) * (ax - p1x) + p1y = ay
```

Lo que nos deja con dos formulas relevantes:

```
tan(alpha) = (p2y - p1y) / (p2x - p1x)
ay = tan(alpha) * (ax - p1x) + p1y
```

#### El problema de los pixeles

En realidad, no es posible hacer una linea perfecta en una imagen. Esto se debe a que una linea abarca numeros decimales, pero no se puede hacer algo como "dibujo este punto en el pixel 0,35".

Esto nos obliga a acercarnos lo más posible usando redondeos, lo que crearía secciones completamente horizontales y/o verticales que en realidad no existen en una linea "diagonal".

Otro detalle a tener en cuenta, es que en una linea hay infinitos puntos, lo cual, incluso sin este problema, hace imposible representar una linea perfecta.

#### El caso de la linea vertical

Este caso es interesante, por que cuando la linea es vertical, no se puede calcular la tangente, esto por que `p2x - p1x` da 0, y como se trata del denominador, no se puede resolver ya que se divide por cero. Esto hará que este caso particular deba ser tratado de una forma especial.

#### El código

```
import tkinter as tk

def rgb_to_hex(rgb):
    """
    Si el color es una cadena, se devuelve sin cambios.
    De lo contrario, se asume que es un iterable de enteros y se convierte
    en hexadecimal.
    """
    
    if(isinstance(rgb, str)):
        return rgb
    else:
        return '#{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}'.format(*rgb)

def drawline(photoimage, x1, y1, x2, y2, color="black"):
    """
    esto usa el método put del PhotoImage para colocar un color.
    El parametro "to" escala el color o la matriz de pixeles para que abarque de x1 y1 a (opcionalmente) x2 y2
    """
    
    color = rgb_to_hex(color)

    # si son flotantes, esto redondea los numeros.
    x1 = int(round(x1))
    x2 = int(round(x2))
    y1 = int(round(y1))
    y2 = int(round(y2))

    # nos aseguramos de que x2 y y2 sean mayores a x1 y y1 respectivamente.
    if(x2 < x1):
        x1, x2 = x2, x1
    if(y2 < y1):
        y1, y2 = y2, y1

    # si la linea es vertical...
    if(x2 == x1):
        photoimage.put(color, to=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    else:
        tan_angle = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)

        for x in range(x1, x2 + 1):
            # calculamos el inicio y el final de la sección vertical:
            # tomamos el pixel inicial y final.
            puty1 = y1 + int(round(tan_angle * (x - x1)))

            # esto elige el y más chico entre el calculado y el y2.
            # Si el calculo resulta en un numero mayor a y2, esto lo establece en y2.
            puty2 = min(y1 + int(round(tan_angle * (x + 1 - x1))), y2)

            photoimage.put(color, to=(x, puty1, x + 1, puty2 + 1))

root = tk.Tk()

image = tk.PhotoImage(width=10, height=11)
image.put("white", to=(0, 0, image.width(), image.height()))
drawline(image, 1, 1, 10, 9)
image = image.zoom(10)


label = tk.Label(root, image=image)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Produce**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

La solución de @Dante S. es muy completa, basándose en la ecuación de la recta. Pero para dibujar rectas mediante pixeles existe un algoritmo muy utilizado llamado [Algoritmo de Bresenham](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Bresenham)

Este algoritmo no requiere calcular la pendiente de la recta, y además hace rectas más "finas" (en los escalones, los píxeles se tocan solo en las esquinas, esto se entiende mejor viendo la imagen final).

La explicación de cómo funciona el algoritmo no es nada sencilla (puedes buscarla en internet), pero su implementación en cambio sí es muy simple. En este caso sería así:

```py
def drawline(photoimage, x1, y1, x2, y2, color="black"):
    """
    Dibuja una linea en una imagen de tkinter utilizando el algoritmo de Bresenham.
    """

    color = rgb_to_hex(color)

    # redondear las coordenadas
    x1, x2, y1, y2 = map(round, (x1, x2, y1, y2))

    dx = abs(x2 - x1)  # distancia horizontal
    dy = abs(y2 - y1)  # distancia vertical

    # Ajustar los signos de los pasos
    sx = 1 if x1 < x2 else -1
    sy = 1 if y1 < y2 else -1

    # Calcular el error inicial
    err = dx - dy

    while True: # Se saldra del bucle cuando se llegue al final de la linea
        # Pintar pixel actual en x1, y1
        photoimage.put(color, to=(x1, y1, x1+1, y1+1))
        if x1 == x2 and y1 == y2: # Hemos terminado!
            break

        # Calcula el error para el siguiente pixel
        e2 = 2 * err

        if e2 > -dy:         # Si el error es mayor o igual que la distancia vertical
            err = err - dy   # Se reduce el error en la distancia vertical
            x1 = x1 + sx     # y se mueve horizontalmente

        if e2 < dx:          # Si el error es menor o igual que la distancia horizontal
            err = err + dx   # Se reduce el error en la distancia horizontal
            y1 = y1 + sy     # y se mueve verticalmente

        # Volver al inicio del bucle
```

Usando esta función el resultado de `drawline(image, 1, 1, 10, 9)` sería ahora:

[image: Resultado]

**Idea básica**. La idea básica del algoritmo es, partiendo del punto x1, y1, movernos hacia el punto x2, y2 incrementando ya sea x o ya sea y (o ambos) de uno en uno (o decrementándolo, según las posiciones relativas de los puntos de inicio y fin). Para decidir cuál de los dos se incrementa (si x o y o ambos) se basa en un "error" que es la diferencia entre la distancia horizontal y la vertical.